# Golang cgo error while loading shared library (libcrypto) on other computers

Tags: go, compilation, openssl, cgo, libcrypto

I wrote a go package that is just a wrapper for a C program, which requires `openssl` to work.

My CGO setup is as follow:

```
// #cgo CFLAGS: -Imy/library/include -Imy/library/src -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/include/openssl -Lmy/library/src -lcrypto
// #include <my_library.c>
// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"
```

I can compile and run it both in my Mac and on a Docker container I created, but when I try to run (it is already compiled) on a different machine I get the error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I make it work also on PCs without `libssl-dev` installed?

Comment: Statically link your program, or install the missing libraries.

Comment: What do you mean by statically link my program?

Comment: So, when on a computer where it does not work, try to search for `libcrypto*` and see what will be found, if any. Chances are, the library will be found but it will have a different so-called "soname" — which would include a different *version* in it (not 1.1).